# Is it possible to give more weight to a keyword while doing a (Google) search?

Tags: google-search

Say I want to search for an error message like `The given filter instance must implement one or more of the following filter interfaces` but in the context of MiniProfiler. Is it possible to give more weight to the `MiniProfiler` part.

In example by enclosing it with asterisks:
`The given filter instance must implement one or more of the following filter interfaces *MiniProfiler*`

Just a theoretical question that popped up in my mind. I think I can find the answer with the current search query too :)

Answer (score 1):

If you put MiniProfiler first, it will have more weight (maybe just slightly). That is my experience. Also, surrounding it by double quotes may help, even with single words, as it definitely changes the results.

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes to give more weight to the term. Previously, the `+` symbol did this, but it has probably been deprecated.

Source: http://searchengineland.com/google-sunsets-search-operator-98189

In your specific example, I would suggest using double quotes for the entire phrase and then using another pair of double quotes for `MiniProfiler`.

For example:
Searching for:

`"The given filter instance must implement one or more of the following filter interfaces" "miniprofiler"`

will show you pages with that error message where the word `MiniProfiler` exists as well, but searching for

`"The given filter instance must implement one or more of the following filter interfaces" miniprofiler`

(without double quotes for the word) will show you web pages with the error message where the word MiniProfiler might or might not exist.

Comment: Thanks for the info on "+" being deprecated, and re-purposing of the quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but I think it is not completely answering the question. As far as I understand you can make single words to be interpreted exactly as they are with enclosing them with double quotes. So "monkeys" won't show up a site with just the word "monkey". I am more wondering about the *order* of the search results.